# Django turn off redirect after login

Tags: django

Is there a way to completely turn off redirection after user login? I just can't find out how to do this... I just don't need any additional queries after login, because it's happening in modal window. I tried to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = None` or `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''` in settings, none of this works. Am I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

So from what i understood you want the login required page to be a modal.

You can't accomplish that using django's login_required, instead you can use ajax.

This must be in your views:

```
def login_required_ajax_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return JsonResponse(data={'logged_in', True})
        return JsonResponse(data={'logged_in', False})
    return HttpResponse("not ajax")  # Add something if the call isn't ajax
```

And this is going to be your javascript in the page:

```
function login_required() {
$.ajax({
   url: 'url goes here',
   data: data
   success: success  //on success call a function checking logged_in is 
                               //true or false then open modal to log in.
})}
```

If it returns true allow them to click the button and move on to the next page.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. Django default behaviour is to redirect to some page after standard login view. I just want to turn it off - all I need is sessionid, which returns in first response in header, but I don't need redirect